# Resharper - runs all unit tests (cannot run a single unit test only using Ctrl +R, T )

Tags: resharper

I cannot run/debug only a single unit test using Ctrl + R, T after installing Resharper 5 (used to be able to do that before). It now runs all of my unit tests. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, my Visual Studio setup has `CTRL+R, T` mapped to Visual Studio's built-in test runner.  You can manually change the keybindings by going to:

`Tools -> Options, Environment ->  Keyboard`

... and assign your shortcut preference to one of these commands:

- ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTest_ContextRun
- ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTest_ContextDebug

Alternatively, you can run a single unit test by using `ALT+R, U, R` to run a single test or `ALT+R, U, D` to debug a single test.